# Angularjs - ngSwitch - Alternatives for Listening .on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Fairly new to Angular. Trying to keep things as simple as possible.

---

**Scenario**: I create a list of blog posts using ng-repeat. They can get filtered one of two ways;
1. By category associated with 1 of 4 anchor tags - One example:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="myFilter={ category: 'news' }" class="news tagged">//stuff</a>
```

or

2. By ID associated with each blog post - Example:

   ```
    <article ng-repeat="b in articles | filter:myFilter" class="blog-post feed-item">
          <a href="#" class="noteLink" ng-click="$parent.myFilter=b"> {{ b.title }} </a>
     <!-- More Elements and the article closing tag below -->
   ```

---

**Problem:** I would like to use ng-switch, with my switch | on expression dependent on which method of filter is being implemented.

---

**Attempted**: 1)Basing the switch expression off of the properties of myFilter but could not figure out how to access them 2.) Adding more properties to the onClick event but was not getting any reaction from the switch listener.

---

**Why I chose this method:** 1. inexperienced and overwhelmed with angular options. 2 I would like to be able to use angulars animate between the switches.

---

Thank You in Advance for your Time,

Steve

Comment: I am known to struggle with explaining my scenario and problem, If anyone thinks some things need more explanation please let me know.

Comment: any chance you can replicate this in a jsfiddle or plunkr?